# CFStream SSL error -9800

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ssl, cfstream

My iOS app contains 2 versions: server and client. Server posts a service via Bonjour and waits for a client. Client searches that services and connects to the server. After that all communications implemented through CFSockets.
Here is my code to set up streams for such communications:

```
- (BOOL)setupSocketStreams {
if ( readStream == nil || writeStream == nil ) {
    return NO;
}
incomingDataBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
outgoingDataBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// Turning SSL on
NSDictionary *sslSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanFalse, (id)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, nil];
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, sslSettings);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, sslSettings);

CFReadStreamSetProperty(
        readStream,
        kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
        kCFBooleanTrue
);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(
        writeStream,
        kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
        kCFBooleanTrue
);

CFOptionFlags registeredEvents =
        kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted     |
                kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable |
                kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes    |
                kCFStreamEventEndEncountered    |
                kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred
;

CFStreamClientContext ctx = {
        0,      // version
        self,   // info
        NULL,   // retain callback
        NULL,   // release callback
        NULL    // copyDescription callback
};

CFReadStreamSetClient(
        readStream,
        registeredEvents,
        readStreamEventHandler,
        &ctx
);
CFWriteStreamSetClient(
        writeStream,
        registeredEvents,
        writeStreamEventHandler,
        &ctx
);

CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(
        readStream,
        CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
        kCFRunLoopCommonModes
);
CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(
        writeStream,
        CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
        kCFRunLoopCommonModes
);

if ( ! CFReadStreamOpen(readStream) || ! CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream)) {
    [self close];
    return NO;
}

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(establishedConnection:)]) {
    [self.delegate establishedConnection:self];
}

return YES;
}
```

Without part that turning SSL on this code works fine, but otherwise I'm getting error:

```
Error:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9800.)
```

What kind of problem can it be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known issue for TLS1.2 support in iOS 5: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2287/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011309

By setting kCFStreamSSLLevel to @"kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_0SSLv3" I was able to fix the -9800 issue in my app.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Full listing of socket setup method located here http://pastebin.com/EDSnmcMd

Comment: HOLY COW. Can't believe that fixed the error I was having trying to connect to Gmail. Would never have figured that out! Thanks.